# SpecSync4MTM problema

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Então pessoal, toda vez que eu tento executar o `specsync4mtm.cmd` me manda

> 'C:\Users\zidan\OneDrive\Documentos\Visual' não é reconhecido como um
>   comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.'

Já adicionei uma variável de ambiente com esse path e o erro persiste. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Consegui remover esse erro mas agora o erro e outro : 

ERROR: A versão das ferramentas "15.0" não é reconhecida. As versões de ferramentas disponíveis são "14.0", "2.0", "3.5", "4.0".  C:\Site_Template_Agil_Teste\SpecFlow_Site_Testes\SpecFlow_Site_Testes.csproj
E como se a versão do meu .csproj nao fosse compativel

Comment: Qual a versão do pacote que está no csproj?

Answer (score 0):

Você deve instalar SpecSync.MTM através do Nuget. Ou por linha de comando:

```
Install-Package SpecSync.MTM -Version 1.6.0
```

As Dlls são instaladas automaticamente pelo pacote.